# MeCab path parameters do not accept whitespace on Windows

Tags: java, mecab

I have successfully used [MeCab Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mecab/files/mecab-java/0.98pre3/.) for calling [Mecab](http://mecab.sourceforge.net) from my Java code.
I use the following statement to initialize the tagger:

```
tagger = new Tagger("--node-format=%f[7]\\t --unk-format=%m\\t --eos-format=\\n --rcfile=" + filePath + "/mecabrc" + " --dicdir=" + filePath + "/ipadic");
```

Now I am facing a problem that `filePath` might actually contain whitespace characters, for example: `c:\folder name\`. When I try using such a path, I get an errors  from Mecab saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\src\c\common\mecab\src\main\c\tagger.cpp(151) [load_dictionary_resource(param)] C:\src\c\common\mecab\src\main\c\param.cpp(71) [ifs] no such file or directory: c:/folder
```

Which means Mecab did not recognize the whitespace correctly.

Any idea how can I direct Mecab to accept the whitescapes in a Windows file path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the MeCab source code and there is no way to get MeCab to accept white space in the path without editing the source and compiling a custom version. You have at least three work-around options:

1. Rename the directory to something without spaces
2. Use a relative path if possible
3. Use windows 8.3 filenames

[Here is a link to showing more information on how to get 8.3 filenames in java.](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/eightpointthree/eightpointthree.html)

Comment: I tried to understand this part of the source but am rusty at C/C++. Can you please let me know what specific part of the MeCab source needed adjusting to get it to accept whitespaces? I have forked mecab for my project and am comfortable with that since it's long-unmaintained upstream. Thank you